Asymptotic in/out state
I have read the following from Weigand's lecture note on QFT (https://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf, page 47, eq.(2.38)-(2.39)):-
These in/out states are formalised by the in- and out-fields $\phi_\text{in}$ and $\phi_\text{out}$. They should have the following properties (as a direct assumption): The in-state $|i\rangle$ is created from the asymptotic vacuum $|\text{vac,in}\rangle$ by action of $\phi_\text{in}$ as $t\to-\infty$. Obviously, we assume that $|\text{vac,in}\rangle=|\Omega\rangle$ - the vacuum of the interacting theory.
$|i\rangle$ has energy $E=\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$ with $m$ the physical mass, i.e. the value of the 1-particle pole in the Feynman propagator of the full interacting theory. Note that $m\ne m_0$ - the mass of free theory. $\phi_\text{in}$ is a free field as assumption, and it obeys the free Klein-Gordan-equation, but with physical mass $m$, i.e. $(\partial^2+m^2)\phi_\text{in}=0$. It is thus possible to expand $\phi_\text{in}$ in terms of $a_\text{in}(\mathbf{p})$ and $a_\text{in}^\dagger(\mathbf{p})$ as mode expansions, like we did for free field ($p^0=\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$):
\begin{equation}
        \phi_\text{in}(x)=\int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\left(a_\text{in}(\mathbf{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}+a_\text{in}^\dagger(\mathbf{p})e^{ip\cdot x}\right).
    \end{equation}
Asymptotically for $t\to -\infty$, the in-field $\phi_\text{in}$ and the total interacting field $\phi$ agree in a suitable manner. We thus assume that $\langle\alpha|\phi|\beta\rangle=C\langle\alpha|\phi_\text{in}|\beta\rangle$ for all $|\alpha\rangle,|\beta\rangle$ and for $t\to-\infty$. Especially if we take $|1_\mathbf{p}\rangle$ and $|\Omega\rangle$, we can prove that $\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi(0)|\Omega\rangle=C\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi_\text{in}(0)|\Omega\rangle.$ By construction, $\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi_\text{in}(0)|\Omega\rangle=1$, so we get $C=\sqrt{Z}$, the wavefunction renormalization constant.
My question are:

How to prove $\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi(0)|\Omega\rangle=C\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi_\text{in}(0)|\Omega\rangle$? The assumption only implies the asymptotic behaviour for $t\to -\infty$. But if I rightly understand, this $0$ means especially $t=0,$ which is obviously not applicable.
Why, by construction, $\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi_\text{in}(0)|\Omega\rangle=1$? If I use the mode expansion for $\phi_\text{in}$, then I get

$$
\langle 1_\mathbf{p}|\phi_{in}(0)|\Omega\rangle=\int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p}'}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p'}}}(2\pi)^32E_p\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}')=\sqrt{2E_p},
$$
which is not $1$.

Link to lecture notes? Chapter, page, eq. number(s)?...

I've added reference in question.
